# A question about conditional expectation involving independence

Tags: probability

If the vector $(u,v)$ is independent of the vector $x$, then I would like to show that
$$E(u|x,v)= E(u|v)$$

The only thing I can derive from the definitions is that if $(u,v)$ is independent of $x$, then $E( (u,v) | x)= E((u,v))$.

I can no longer attack this problem!

Help

Comment: What level do you want your answer at? Discrete random variables? Everything with densities? The Kolmogorov formulation of a conditional expectation as a Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well assuming the random variables are absolutely continuous, you can use densities:

$$f(u|x,v)=\frac{f(u,v,x)}{f(x,v)}=\frac{f(u,v)f(x)}{f(x,v)}=\frac{f(u|v)f(v)f(x)}{f(x,v)}=f(u|v),$$

where the second and last equalities use independence between $x$ and $(u,v)$.

Comment: You may proceed analogously using mass functions if they are discrete